# Update two fields with multiple lines in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my js

```
$(function() {
    var tryme = 5;
    var options = {
    source: "<?=base_url()?>/autocomplete/",
    minLength: 1,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.value = ui.item.valuedesc;
    //$(this).siblings('.item_sku').val(ui.item.valuedesc); // not working
    //$(this).siblings('.description').val(ui.item.description); // not working
    //$(this).siblings('.rate').val(ui.item.rate); // not working
    }
    };
    $( ".item_sku" ).autocomplete(options);


    $(".add-row").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var cloned = $('#invoice_table tr:last').clone();
        cloned.appendTo('#invoice_table').find('input').val('');
        cloned.find('.item_sku').autocomplete(options);
    });
});
```

I am using jquery to clone a line of fields in order to build my invoice items.

What is NOT working now is the specific line of fields are not updating.

These are my fields:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="255" name="item_sku[]" data-required="1" class="form-control item_sku" autocomplete="off" required/>

<input type="text" maxlength="255" name="item_description[]" id="description" data-required="1" class="form-control calculate description" required/>

<input type="text" maxlength="255" name="item_amount[]" data-required="1" class="form-control calculate rate" autocomplete="off" required/>
```

So when I start typing int he ITEM_SKU field, I get my autocomplete options - which is working fine. And when I click on it, it must update the description and item_amount textfields.

Now if I change the field class to an ID, and the javascript to example

```
<input type="text" maxlength="255" name="item_amount[]" id="rate" data-required="1" class="form-control calculate" autocomplete="off" required/>
```

It works.

But because I have an "add more fields" button - I have to have multiple fields with the same ID.

How can I get the current line's fields updated with `ui.item.description` and `ui.item.rate`?

http://i.share.pho.to/7945c43f_o.jpeg

Comment: Have an array and add an iterator to your array like so

var i = 1
<input type="text" maxlength="255" name="item_amount[i]" id="rate" data-required="1" class="form-control calculate" autocomplete="off" required/>

Then simply increase i by 1

Comment: here is the jsfiddle but read the comments http://jsfiddle.net/benniecpt/c5ajonav/

Comment: Basically ID's need to be unique. When cloning, you **must** change the IDs to something unique. Use a counter or similar

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `hidden div` as a *library* for your cloned elements...
Also, remove the `ID` after the obj is cloned.

something like <sup>(untested)</sup>

```
$(".add-row").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var cloned = $('#hidden').find('#tr').clone().removeAttr('id');
    cloned.appendTo('#invoice_table');
    cloned.find('.item_sku').autocomplete(options);
});
```

---

***Edit***: Simplify jsfiddle example <sup>(tested)</sup>  http://jsfiddle.net/c5ajonav/3/